# SQL table with many foreign keys VS lots of tables pointing to it

Tags: sql, relational

New to SQL.
This example is contrived but demostrates the concepts:
I have a comments table which can be related to many other tables.
For example, members have comments, posts have comments, ETC.
My question is, is it best to have the comments table linking to all the tables it's associated with?
So it would have a memberid, topicid, ETC.
Or should members and topics have an accountid?

What are the Pros and cons of both?
Thanks.

Comment: A contrived example is no good since any real world application is going to have constraints that will push you in one direction or another.  Not sure what "members have comments" means, and certainly have no idea what "ETC." encompasses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably set up my tables something like this:

Post

- PostId
- MemberId
- Content/extra fields

Comment

- CommentId
- MemberId
- PostId
- Content/extra fields

Member

- MemberId
- Name/extra fields

So Posts are made by members, and comments are made by members on a post.
Posts has a fk relationship to member
and comment 2 fk relationships.